# What is autophagy?

Tags: autophagy

Recently Japanese scientist won Nobel Prize in Medicine for **"Autophagy"**.

Can someone explain what autophagy is?

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.livescience.com/amp/56349-japanese-scientist-wins-nobel-prize-in-medicine.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic unless directly related to medical care.

Comment: @CareyGregory I've edited the question. Is it valid for the site now?

Comment: You fixed the nutrition problem but asking how this will benefit people is purely speculative, and therefore opinion. So I edited your question down to the root question you're asking and reopened it. People can add their thoughts on what it might lead to in their answers, but get the basic question answered first.

Comment: Welcome, @Saksham, I've closed your question as a duplicate because I think a Q&A here already answers your question. This isn't any sort of punishment, it's just the way SE is meant to streamline questions. If you have further questions that are not answered in the marked duplicate you can ask a new one. Thanks!